# Unit to measure Ferromagnetic Strength

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

Imagine I have a 1T magnet that is stuck to a 3mm iron ball. Then I took some more iron balls and stuck them one under another, making a chain. Now if I do the same with cobalt or nickel, other ferromagnetic elements that are weaker than iron, would they make a chain just as long? Also, how can we measure the strength of a ferromagnetic element? Is there any unit to do that?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that cobalt and nickel "are weaker than iron"? What quantity are you using to tell which one is stronger?

Comment: I meant to say that iron is a better ferromagnet than the others.

Comment: In order to say this you must have some parameter in mind. How do you know which one is better? What difference in behaviour makes you say that one is better?

Answer (score 0):

Atoms with an odd number of electrons have a magnetic dipole moment. In a ferromagnetic metal these tend to swing into alignment with an externally applied magnetic field, and inter-atomic forces help them to maintain this alignment in spite of thermal agitation.  This alignment gives rise to a new magnetic field, which in some alloys can be much stronger than the external field (thus the use of iron cores in many devices). Typically, if the external field is removed, the atomic dipoles drop  back into alignment with the handiest crystal axis.  This leaves a “remnant” magnetization (dipole moment/unit volume).  In some new alloys (permanent magnets) this can be quite strong.  In other applications (like transformers) you would prefer no remnant field (which would require energy to reverse).  There are many possible alloys, and each has its own set of magnetic properties.

Comment: Iron has 26 electrons and *is* "ferromagnetic", so is NIckel with 28 electrons; Hund's rule does not need that the atom have odd number of electrons.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to make a ferromagnet stronger than iron?

Comment: In both paramagnetic and ferromagnetic material the atomic dipoles align with external fields.  The difference is that in ferromagnetics the atomic moments align spontaneously forming domains, in the absence of any field.